# html submit button link to next page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <a href="main.jsp" <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" id="submit"  value="Log In">> </a>
```

This is the code I have for my html. I want to make that submit button to link to my main page.
When I do that, I does shot '>' button and it goes into next page.
I just want it to look like original submit button instead of '>'

Comment: what a poor html, you CAN'T nest `input` and `a` tags. What are you up to ? The submit button can't link to a page, it sends the current form values (have you a form ?) to a page. If you want to link to the main page, a A tag is pretty enough. Please explain what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @Pierre I'm obviously beginner of this. Slowly learning. I want my submit button to link to my other page when I click it.

Comment: <a> tags, also called "links" are used to link to other pages. In your case, you'd use <a> tag, styled to look like a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with @pierre, just use the `a` tag

```
 <a href="main.jsp" <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" id="submit"  value="Log In">> </a>
```

Becomes

```
 <a href="main.jsp" class="fadeIn fourth">Log In</a>
```

Then just add whatever styles you wanted for the input to the `a` tag. Also you have a double `>` after the input tag, which doesn't have a closing. So could this be what you want?

```
 <a href="main.jsp"><input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" id="submit"  value="Log In" /></a>
```

**Edits**

```
<input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" id="submit" onclick="link_data" value="Log In" />
<script>
function link_data() {
    // Send data
    window.location.href = "main.jsp"; // This will change the page location to main.jsp
}
</script>
```

If you want it to look like a button without the input please have a look at [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_basic) or make your own using CSS

Comment: I've tried that before, but it does not go to my main.jsp

Comment: Can You explain if you are getting any errors? Blank pages? And if the main.jsp is in the same folder

Comment: When I click on submit button, it refreshes and stays on the same page. The main.jsp is in the same folder but I do not have javascript. Maybe this could be why?

Comment: Well if you are attempting to send data between this page and main.jsp then you will need either a form or javascript to send the data. As you can see in the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txo70f3g/ the html link is working

Comment: So when I put the text between <a> tag like :  <a href="main.jsp"><input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" id="submit"  value="Log In" />submit</a>, then the submit text links to the main page but if I don't put any text, the login button does not link to main page.

Comment: As @Pierre said, you don't need an input within this. If you still want to use an input please have a look at my edits as you will need to use javascript

Comment: Then how do I make it look like a button without input? I don't want it to be just text form

Comment: you can use an image or some css stuff to create a fake submit button, if it's what you intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

FYI --- if your submit button just links to a page, none of the information you're trying to submit will actually go anywhere. If you want the submit button to actually submit something, you're going to need some Javascript.